# Как получить логи при установке msi?

Tags: c#, cmd

Устанавливаю установочник setup.msi, Я увидел возможность запись логов в файл, но мне нужно выводить логи в StandardOutput?
Вот такой код:

```
Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.Arguments = $"/l \"Setup.msi\" /q";
        processInfo.FileName = "msiexec";

        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        process.StartInfo = processInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, примерно запуск установщика может выглядеть как то так:

```
    public bool InstallFile(string file)
    {
      bool rez = true;
      string fullPath = GetTempPath() + file;
      Logger.WriteLog("InstallFile: path=" + fullPath);
      string currentInstallLogFileName = "";
      try
      {
        // string fullPath = GetTempPath() + p;
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
          Logger.WriteLog("file " + fullPath + " exist");
          //string sw = GetSystemDrive() + @"\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /qn /i ";
          //string tCmd = sw + fullPath;
          //WriteLog("Process.Start(" + tCmd + ")");
          currentInstallLogFileName = GetInstallLogFileName();
          Process pr = new Process();
          pr.StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\msiexec.exe";
          pr.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/qn /i " + fullPath + @" /l*+ """ + currentInstallLogFileName + @"""";
          pr.Start();
          Logger.WriteLog("InstallFile: installation process start successfully");
          while(!pr.HasExited)
          {
            Logger.WriteLog("InstallFile: waiting");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
          }
          bool analyzeLogFileRez = AnalyzeLogFile(currentInstallLogFileName);
          if (analyzeLogFileRez)
          {
            Logger.WriteLog("InstallFile: installation process completed successfully");
          }
          else
          {
            Logger.WriteLog("InstallFile: INSTALLATION PROCESS RETURN ERROR");
            rez = false;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          Logger.WriteLog("file " + fullPath + " not exist");
          rez = false;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logger.WriteLog("Error in InstallFile(): ");
        Logger.WriteLog(ex.Message);
        Logger.WriteLog(ex.Source);
        Logger.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace);
        rez = false;
      }
      return rez;
    }
```

На самом деле, я просто "выдрал" эту процедуру из своего проекта, который делал примерно то же, что Вам нужно.

Здесь есть кое что лишнее, но основная иедя понятна: Вы говорите Msiexec'у, в какой файл писать лог, потом ждете завершения процесса установки, а потом анализируете этот файл.

Мне кажется, Ваш код тоже можно подправить, добавив в него еще буквально пару строк - и тогда у Вас заработает тот же самый сценарий.

В каком то смысле это костыль, и, веротяно, я не додумался, как направить вывод в standard output. Подумаю на досуге...

Успехов!

Comment: `Sleep(1000)` - нехорошо. Есть же `WaitForExit` и `WaitForExitAsync` )

Comment: @aepot - спасибо за подсказку, при случае - поправлю свой код. Писал во времена NET 3.5, молодой еще был :-)

Comment: Во времена 3.5 я писад только скрипты под bash/sh. А дотнет казался кривой тормознутой дикостью.